# How to debug angular 2 app which is using webpack

Tags: google-chrome, angular, debugging

I am using **angular: "2.4.8"**, **webpack: "1.14.0"**, **webpack-dev-server: "1.16.2"**. visual studio code was **updated at** **February 2017**. I want to debug my app in the chrome browser. My chrome file structure looks like the below image:[image: screenshot of debugger in the browser]

**Question Update:**

You can see webpack.config.js and folder structure in the screenshot given below: [image]

Comment: have you added `devtool:"source-map"` option in the config?

Comment: @Jai thanks a lot. Can you please add it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Just refer to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E39yv.png) image. In the console go to sources, and then expand localhost and under the "webpack://", the "." folder, and there is your source code.

Comment: there is no such webpack:// folder under localhost

Comment: after I added devtool:"source-map" in webpack.config.js file I got such a folder and now I can debug my application. Thanks a lot. @M. Samard